# PX4 with ROS2: which Ubuntu Linux development environment is necessary?

Tags: installation, ros, ros2, gazebo-simu, px4

I am attempting to construct the environment to run PX4 with ROS2 Foxy on Ubuntu 20.04.
So far I have been following this [guide](https://docs.px4.io/v1.12/en/ros/ros2_comm.html) and I was able to get to the very end of it, in particular to the section "Sanity Check the Installation".
Following strictly the indications, the first step is: "**[Setup your PX4 Ubuntu Linux development environment](https://docs.px4.io/v1.12/en/dev_setup/dev_env_linux_ubuntu.html) - the default instructions get the latest version of PX4 source and install all the needed tools**".

In the provided link there are different possible paths, given the warning:

> ROS users must follow the instructions for: ROS/Gazebo.

I imagined it would be best to follow those, but they are made specifically for Ubuntu 18.04 and ROS melodic. I then reverted to the "standard" installation specified in: the section "**Gazebo, JMAVSim and NuttX (Pixhawk) Targets**", but running the command:

```
make px4_sitl_rtps gazebo
```

I receive a huge series of errors and warnings that is honestly very hard to debug. 
Is there an error in my steps possibly? Is there a ROS/Gazebo installation that is up to date with ROS2?

Thanks.